# How to import constants from another file on TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

This is embarrassing to ask, but I'm trying to separate all constants into a new file and just import it, to keep things clean. However, nothing I've tried works, and all other questions here on SO seem to revolve around importing classes and functions.

I have a file called `constants.tsx`, where all the constants are declared:

```
export const default_bg               = "#2456a5"
export const default_light_font_color = "white"
export const default_lg_font_size     = 11
export const default_md_font_size     = 10
export const default_sm_font_size     = 9
export const default_dark_font_color  = "#000028"
export const default_font             = "arial"
```

And a main file with all the functionality so far, `App.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Header } from './Header';
import { Body } from './Body';

import * as defaults from 'constants'

...
```

However, `defaults` (or any other name I give the import) doesn't seem to contain the constants. Writing `defaults.default_bg` gives me this error:

> TS2339: Property 'default_bg' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   import("constants")'.

And `console.log(defaults)` prints:

[image]

I know this is probably extremely simple, but I can't figure out how to do this. I'm new to Typescript and Javascript in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> import * as defaults from 'constants'

The above tells node to look inside `/node_modules` for a `constants` module.

Change that line to:

`import * as defaults from './path/to/constants'`

As for what's being printed to the console, that's another matter since it's certainly putting something in your `defaults` import identifier.

Answer (score 2):

This its my actual approach:

**constant.ts**

```
export const default = {

bg               : "#2456a5"
light_font_color : "white"
lg_font_size     : 11
md_font_size     : 10
sm_font_size     : 9
dark_font_color  : "#000028"
font             : "arial"

} as const;
```

**app.ts**

```
import { default } from "./path/to/constant";
...
console.log('Default Font: ', default.font);
```